# How to sort a column of a data frame(mtcars) in descending order where the column value is greater than 20 in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Below script did fetch me the results but it also prints the value of new data frame(cars) created.

```
mtcars[which(mtcars$mpg>20),]
cars<- mtcars[which(mtcars$mpg>20),]
print(cars[order(-cars$mpg),])
```

Can it be done in a different way?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I don't understand your question. You seem to have done it right, what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to do this in a different way.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  filter(mpg>20) %>%
  arrange(desc(mpg)) -> result

result

#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch/print only names you can use this approach also

```
library(dplyr)

row.names(arrange(filter(mtcars, mpg>20), -mpg))

 [1] "Toyota Corolla" "Fiat 128"       "Honda Civic"    "Lotus Europa"   "Fiat X1-9"      "Porsche 914-2" 
 [7] "Merc 240D"      "Datsun 710"     "Merc 230"       "Toyota Corona"  "Hornet 4 Drive" "Volvo 142E"    
[13] "Mazda RX4"      "Mazda RX4 Wag"
```